# should we call ourselves salafi or ahlul hadith to deal with innovators?

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, salafi

Some people say. That our label is Muslim. But when dealing with innovators we should call ourselves salafi or ahlul hadith. Is this true?

I personally think calling ourselves Muslim is enough. But they don't listen.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer you are right.

It is actually the term used in the qur'an describing the people who follow Allah's guidance:

- > Our Lord, and make us Muslims [in submission] to You and from our descendants a Muslim nation [in submission] to You. And show us our rites and accept our repentance. Indeed, You are the Accepting of repentance, the Merciful. ([2:128](https://legacy.quran.com/2/128))
- > And you do not resent us except because we believed in the signs of our Lord when they came to us. Our Lord, pour upon us patience and let us die as Muslims [in submission to You]." ([7:126](https://legacy.quran.com/7/126))
- > Indeed, the Muslim men and Muslim women, the believing men and believing women, the obedient men and obedient women, the truthful men and truthful women, the patient men and patient women, the humble men and humble women, the charitable men and charitable women, the fasting men and fasting women, the men who guard their private parts and the women who do so, and the men who remember Allah often and the women who do so - for them Allah has prepared forgiveness and a great reward. ([33:35](https://legacy.quran.com/33/35))

While the other terms have been created/innovated by later generations of Muslims to describe groups among the Muslim Ummah. So from a **linguistic** or **historical** perspective these terms are bid'ah.